# jQuery Animation on hover a li

Tags: jquery, animation, mouseover, jquery-hover

I want have animation on hovering a

which shall slide from top and on mouseout it shall slidetop.
 I have done all but there is a little problem.
Please view my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/amitabhaghosh197/DSusn/)

My codes are 
CSS

```
    #nav{width:200px;
height:60px;
background:#096;
list-style:none;
} 

 #nav li
 {
     width:200px;
     height:60px;
     float:left;
     position:relative;

}

     #nav li a
     {
         width:200px;
         height:50px;
         background:#09F;
         color:#000;
         display:block;
         position:relative;
         margin:0;
         z-index:100;

         }

         #nav li a:hover
         {
             color:#fff;
             }

         #nav li .hover
         { width:200px;
         height:50px;
         background:#000;
         color:#0FF;
        display:none;
       background-position:0 0;
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
         margin:0;
         z-index:0;
         opacity:0.9;

             }
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function()
 {    
  $('#nav li a').append('<div class="hover">');

  $('#nav li a').hover(function (){
      $('.hover').stop(true, true).slideDown('1000');    

        }, 

        //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
        function() {

            $('.hover').stop(true, true).slideUp('1000');   

    }).click (function () {

        //Add selected class if user clicked on it
        $(this).addClass('selected');


      });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">

   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>


  </ul>
```

But I am viewing only the .hover div is sliding but my Home text is not viewing. I have added z-index to  tag also but then also the text is not viewing while slide is working.

Please help me to sort it out.
Thanks to everyone in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `z-index: -1` for `.hover`. It will solve the problem.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DSusn/2/

And pay attention to your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` calls. If you need to set speed as number of milliseconds, its' arguments should be an integer, i.e. without quotes `fadeIn(1000)`.

Comment: thanks VisionN I have done it. But I am seeing it in IE it is not working. Can you please suggest how to code additionally for IE so that it works properly in IE.

Comment: Hm. It should work fine in IE. I do have IE9 and it works fine.

Comment: Yes I have solved the problem. What I have done just a change in script    $('#nav li a').append('<div class="hover"><\/div>'); and  $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).fadeIn('1000'); The problem for viewing in IE I have seen it is resolved when uploaded in my server . But while working from Local browser it is not working in IE. I don't know why? You can see it in this link  http://amitabha.in/mock/animate/index2.html

Comment: Hm. `amitabha.in` linbk doesn't seem to be openning. However, in your updated fiddle you still have `z-index: 0`.

Comment: sorry the updated fiddle I have mentioned wrong you can view it here http://jsfiddle.net/amitabhaghosh197/DSusn/5/

Comment: Thanks again VisionN. Actually I am new in jQuery and JSFiddle so it shall take few time for me